# Android X86 VM on Hyper-V has no network connection

Tags: networking, windows, android-x86, virtualization, ethernet

I followed [these instructions](https://linustechtips.com/topic/764366-guide-how-to-run-android-x86-on-hyper-v/) to install an Android X86 virtual machine on top of Hyper-V inside windows OS. However, now the VM has no internet connectivity. Here are my network settings:

[image]

can you be kind to help me know what is the problem and how I can resolve it?

Comment: Android-x86 does not contains the necessary ethernet adapter driver for the virtual network card provided by Hyper-V. Use a "legacy network adapter" instead, not sure if this will work. In general the driver support of Android-x86 is very limited, you can find plenty of questions here caused by problems with non-working display, network and so on.

Comment: @Robert can you elaborate a bit on how the `legacy network adapter` can be implemented? is it inside the hyper-V settings or inside the ANdroid VM itself? how come it works in [this Youtube video](https://youtu.be/-8_yeGLnaCg)? 

Comment: Of course it is in hyper-V, it is already mentioned in your screen shot.